# jquery return from function?

Tags: jquery, function, return

I'm trying to understand the right way to return values in jquery from a function. I've checked the API as well as other questions here and I can't find the correct way to do this. All I want is a simple variable to be returned so I can set it as a global variable. Here's what I got:

```
var a = 0, b, c;
var imgArr = [];

  $(document).ready(function() { //populates array with images

        var smooth = popArr();
        alert(smooth);
  }

 function popArr(){
        $("#thumb_slider").children().each(function(index, element) {
            var newImg = $("<img />").attr({
                src: this.src,
                alt: 'space'
            }).addClass(index == 0 ? "left_slot" : (index == 1 ? "middle_slot" : "right_slot"));
            imgArr.push(newImg);
          return imgArr;               // This comes back as undefined.

        });
    }
```

My question is why is it returning undefined? Am I even supposed to use "return" in Jquery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You try to return something from the `.each` callback. The only useful return value of this function is `false` to cancel the "loop" early.

Simply move your return statement after the `});` and everything should work fine.

You can also avoid the global variable - you return the array so there's no need to make it global:

```
function popArr() {
    var imgArr = [];
    $("#thumb_slider").children().each(function (index, element) {
        var newImg = $("<img />").attr({
            src: this.src,
            alt: 'space'
        }).addClass(index == 0 ? "left_slot" : (index == 1 ? "middle_slot" : "right_slot"));
        imgArr.push(newImg);
    });
    return imgArr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was really helpful. Can't believe I was that close.

Answer (score 0):

the method `popArr()` is not returning anything. instead, it is calling `.each()`

since it is a global variable, just pushing elements into it will be enough.